# Can I set/unset a default Coder in Scio?

Tags: serialization, apache-beam, spotify-scio

I would like to consistently apply a custom `RicherIndicatorCoder` for my case class `RicherIndicator`. Moreover if I fail to provide a new Coder for `Tuples` or `KVs` containing `RicherIndicator` then I would like to obtain a compile-time or runtime error rather than fall back on a suboptimal coder.

However Scio does not seem to honor the `@DefaultCoder` annotation:

```scala
@DefaultCoder(classOf[RicherIndicatorCoder]) // Ignored
case class RicherIndicator (
  policy: Policy,
  indicator: Indicator
)
```

Nor does Scio give priority to custom coders registered with the `CoderRegistry`, instead falling back on its own default coder:

```scala
val registry = sc.pipeline.getCoderRegistry
registry.registerCoderForClass(classOf[RicherIndicator], RicherIndicatorCoder.of) // Not used
```

Therefore I must use `setCoder(RicherIndicatorCoder.of)` wherever an `SCollection` of this type appears, and carefully comb through the pipeline in case there are composite types which include a `RicherIndicator`.

Is there a way to set my custom coder as the default, or to disable falling back on the default Magnolia or Kryo based coder?

Answer (score 0):

Java annotation does not work in Scala. You can wrap your Beam `Coder` as an implicit Scio `Coder` like this:

`implicit val richIndicateCoder = Coder.beam(RicherIndicatorCoder)`

It should be picked up as long as the implicit is in scope.

Comment: I was under the impression that Scala supports Java annotation, so was thinking this was an issue with Scio having its own concept of coder defaults and prioritization?

Comment: Sorry I was thinking annotation processor. In this case yeah it's most likely Scio's coder resolution takes precedence, and/or the annotation doesn't work well on Scala classes.